# How to make Visual Studio on Mac break on error line instead of breaking in the main class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

When I'm debugging my project and I encounter a runtime error the debugger stops on the main line instead of the error line.

using AppKit;

```
namespace Project {
    static class MainClass {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            NSApplication.Init();
            NSApplication.Main(args); // breaks here
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of error line:

```
if (isTrue) {
    button.Title = "Title"; // Object reference not set to an instance of an object
}
```

Is there a way to change this so it breaks on the line that has the error?

[image]

[image]
[image]
I tried the Ignore option:

[image]

However, it is unchecked the next time around:

[image]

Comment: I am guessing that code that throws an exception is not in a try catch, otherwise you could put a breakpoint in the catch. On VS Mac you could try creating an exception catchpoint by opening the Breakpoints window, then clicking New Exception Catchpoint and specifying the exception in that dialog. There is also a preview feature in preferences Other - Preview Features - Ability to ignore first-chance exceptions by location or type, which might be another thing to try here.

Comment: I tried and selected "Ignore" and it still lands on the same spot

Comment: FWIW: "ignore" is the opposite of what is wanted here. If it makes it to the MainClass, then its already "too late" to stop at the exception line.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in Visual Studio for Mac:

1. Go to the main menu `View -> Debug Windows -> Breakpoints`
2. Click the `New Exception Catchpoint` button (or `Breakpoint` instead of *Catchpoint*)
3. Leave the options pretty much as they are, i.e.:

   a) *Breakpoint Action* = `Pause the program`

   b) *When to Take Action* = `When an exception is thrown` (*"System.Exception"*; Include subclasses = `true`)
4. Confirm by clicking the `Create` button
5. That's it. Start the project (the main menu `Run -> Start Debugging` or just hit the play button in the toolbar) and enjoy catching the errors

Comment: Yes, worked for me on Visual Studio for Mac Preview, v17.0 Preview.

Comment: For me, the button in step 2 is: "New Exception Breakpoint...", not "Catchpoint". :)

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I'm on `Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.10.22 (build 11)`.

Comment: how to remove that newly added exception catchpoint ?

Comment: @RonakShethia when I right-click on the breakpoint in that list I can choose from `disable breakpoint` or `remove breakpoint`

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Certainly the easiest way (if you know you're looking for a particular error) is to enable (check) the corresponding exception in the exceptions window (Debug->Windows->Exception settings->Common Language Exceptions). Since NREs are nothing you would expect at runtime, this works quite ok for these.

What you want is typically the default behavior, if the exception is unhandled and on the main thread. If the exception happens in a task or async method, things truly get a bit ugly, because then the exception is first wrapped to an `AggregateException` which is later thrown to the main thread when the task is awaited for.

When you get that undesired behavior, do you still have the correct location in the call stack? You might also need to disable "just my code" if the exception happens in a different module.

Comment: Here's what I see on the Debugging preferences pane (added image to post).

Comment: Oh, I was not seeing that you're working on a mac, but I'm confused as to why this is that different. C# development should be the same regardless of platform. Do you have different options available _while_ the debugger is active?

Comment: @PMF It's different, because the Mac IDE evolved from Mono. It's not a port of Visual Studio sadly. It's just a sad version of VS.