# How to connect and print with Bluetooth printer in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have worked on Xamarin android and in android I am able to print with Bluetooth printer but I am not able to find any solution that work on Xamarin IOS.

Is any dependency services can be used to find near by devices in Xamarin IOS and Print it on any Bluetooth device.

Comment: What sort of Bluetooth printer?  Your printer will either need to support BLE so that you can use Core Bluetooth or it will need to have an MFi sdk that you can include in your app. You cannot use legacy Bluetooth SPP

Comment: What worked for Android?  Why doesn’t it work in iOS?

Comment: @Jason i am able to print anything with the Xamarin android in bluetooth printer but it doesn't work in IOS ,also i am not able to scan the bluetooth printer

Comment: @Abhi how are you able to print with Android? What library are you using?

Comment: @Saamer i have used the shiny library "https://www.xamboy.com/2020/04/20/bluetooth-printing-in-xamarin-forms-using-shiny/" and one more blog for the android "https://ozaksut.com/xamarin-forms-bluetooth-printer-chapter-1-android/"

Comment: Did you place an exception catchpoint https://stackoverflow.com/a/71780866/11104068 and read the application output logs, and you don't see any errors?

Comment: @Saamer no i am not getting any error except i am not getting device in search, i am getting every devices on scanning except the bluetooth printer

Comment: @Abhi if you use any other iOS app, are you able to see that bluetooth printer in the list?